# How to add geotiff to layers list?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, layer, geotiff

I have successfully added a tiff image to my leaflet map using leaflet-geotiff.
As shown in this example: https://codepen.io/VictorVelarde/pen/ZKJWMb/

```
var tiff = "https://ihcantabria.github.io/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field/data/tz850.tiff";
fetch(tiff).then(r => r.arrayBuffer()).then(function(buffer) {
  var s = L.ScalarField.fromGeoTIFF(buffer);
  let layer = L.canvasLayer.scalarField(s, {color: chroma.scale("RdPu").domain(s.range)}).addTo(map);
  layer.on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.value !== null) {
      let popup = L.popup()
      .setLatLng(e.latlng)
      .setContent(`${e.value}`)
      .openOn(map);
    }
  });

  map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
});
```

I want to add this image as a layer in the layers panel. For this purpose I use: https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

How do I add the TIFF image as a layer?

Comment: TIFF files aren't really images-- they can contain any sort of data. In this case, you overlay the TIFF by converting it to something that looks like an image. You could instead convert it to an image (after transforming the data to a 2D array of pixels) and use that instead.

Comment: It works great as a TIFF. I just want to add it as a layer so it can be toggled on and off.

Comment: You're actually overlaying a ScalarField, not a TIFF. Just convert the ScalarField to an images and you can use it that way